# Graph in which greedy algorithm for maximum matching is a 2-approximation

Tags: graphs, approximation, greedy-algorithms, matching, bipartite-matching

Here is a greedy algorithm for maximum bipartite matching:

> Iteratively select an edge that is not incident to previously selected edges.

This algorithm returns a 2-approximation, and runs in linear time.

My question is, how can I find a graph for which the greedy algorithm returns a matching which is half as big as the maximum matching?

Comment: a simple path on $3$ edges?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Thanks for your response. my script says 2.optimal, but I also believe that it doesn't work and maybe 1/2.opt is maint.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Is there a graph family for which this algorithm generally gives 1/2 opt?

Comment: Take two star graphs and add an edge between their center vertices.

Comment: Many simple paths on 3 edges.

Comment: A more interesting question is what happens when the greedy algorithm chooses a *random* compatible edge (perhaps according to some scoring function). The expected approximation ratio should still be $1/2$, but examples are harder to come by. For example, if we choose a random starting edge, then the example of a path on 3 edges has approximation ratio of 5/6. (Note that there is always some nondeterministic choice which results in an optimal solution.)